# How to pick a full size image(not thumbnail) from gallery?

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio, android-gallery

**This code just picks the thumbnail of the image cause Im displaying the image in a imageView, but I need the full size image is there a way to change it?**

Archivo.java

```
 pick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    REQUEST_IMAGE_PICK = 1;
                    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    pickIntent.setType("image/*");
                    String[] mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg","image/png"};
                    pickIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES,mimeTypes);
                    startActivityForResult(pickIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_PICK);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toasty.warning(getApplicationContext(), IC, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();

                }
            }
        });
```

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedimage= data.getData();
            if (imagenString == null) {
                String[] filePathColumn ={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedimage,filePathColumn,null,null,null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnindex);
                cursor.close();
                Bitmap mybitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(mybitmap);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "This code just picks the thumbnail of the image" -- not really. How have you reached this conclusion? Note that this code is not reliable and is overly complicated. You would be better served just using the `Uri` directly, perhaps with an image-loading library like Glide or Picasso.

Comment: @CommonsWare Im displaying the image on Screen and the diplayed image is the one on the thumbnail not the original image

Comment: @CommonsWare wait a minute you are right I think that the image its just rotated for some reason and it's getting cropped and looks like the thumbnail

Comment: "the image its just rotated for some reason" -- if the image is a photo, then instructions for how it should be rotated may be in the EXIF headers. If you use an image-loading library like Glide or Picasso, they take care of that for you, along with loading the image on a background thread (so your UI does not freeze briefly).